# Speed difference Word vs Excel looping through Names in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Okay, I have an Excel file with an insane amount of named ranges (17k), but need to loop through the names from Word. So in Excel VBA I can do this:

```
x = 0
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    x = x + 1
Next n
```

That takes about 10-20ms for this 17k names and a bit longer when I do something inside the loop. From Word I can do this:

```
Dim xlsapp As Object
Set xlsapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set wb = xlsapp.ActiveWorkbook
x = 0
For Each n In wb.Names
    x = x + 1
Next n
```

That takes about 10.000-11.000ms, so 1000x as long. Does anyone have an idea why that is? But more importantly: is there a way to loop through the Excel names from Word that's not this slow?

Comment: VBA code in a module in Excel runs *in-process*. VBA code in Word which works with Excel objects runs *out-of-process*. You would find a similar performance hit if you compare VBA in Excel to a .Net solution

Comment: Using such an automation, the code will be slower, as also stated above. But **you can call the Excel sub** if you have it (in Personal.xlsb, or in a different workbook/add-in)... If you place a reference to Excel and change `Dim xlsapp As Object` with `Dim xlsapp As Excel.Application` it may run a little faster, too.

Comment: Agree with @TmothyRylatt. You can try Dim nms as Excel.Names : Set nms = wb.Names on the Word side to try to retrieve the entire Names collection in one go, then process on the Word side, but that doesn't work either. The Set executes very quickly but iterating the set is as slow as your existing loop.